# Does the ContentResolver notify all path variants?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

My content uri has a path depending on the content, e.g. `content://controller/ContentItem/0/Favorites/RecentlyPlayed`

I observed that when I insert something with this uri all other uris with a shorter path also be notified.

**Example**

I insert something at:

```
content://controller/ContentItem/0/Favorites/RecentlyPlayed
```

also notified:

```
content://controller/ContentItem/0/Favorites
content://controller/ContentItem/0
content://controller/ContentItem
```

Is this the usual behavior?

Ralph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes if you passed `true` for `notifyForDescendents` when registering that observer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver%28android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29)

Comment: It looks that this is the right answer but I think it isn't possible to do this with a Cursor. With a Cursor I call `setNotificationUri(ContentResolver cr, Uri notifyUri, int userHandle)` but can't change the `notifyForDescendents` flag :-(